# How to 'ignore' an index out of range error in Python

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life, indexoutofrangeexception

My teacher set me the task to make a Python version of "The Game of Life",
So after I got most of the code working. I got stuck on what I suspect would be a rather common problem: The corners and edges don't have 8 neighbors. So using the following code would give me an index out of range exception:

```
neighbors = (a[x-1][y-1]+a[x-1][y]+a[x-1][y+1]+a[x][y-1]+a[x][y+1]
             +a[x+1][y-1]+a[x+1][y]+a[x+1][y+1])
```

So instead of using a lot of `if` statements, I wanted to catch the indexes that are out of range and pass the value 0 instead.
How would I attempt to do that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: If you want to assume zeros outside, I would just pad your original array with a border or zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a helper function that you could call that would either return a value or zero (pseudocode):

```
def getValue(x, y)
   if x < 0 or y < 0 or x > xbound or y > ybound:
       return 0
   return a[x][y]
```

Then you can call `getValue` a bunch of times with different parameters

Comment: Would be more Pythonic to use a `try/except` in the function. Should probable pass `a` to it, too.

Comment: I agree with the use of `try/except`, but I can't figure out a way to do it more effectively than just using the `getValue(x, y)` function

Comment: I meant use `try/except` in your function rather than bounds testing the indices. Regardless it's going to require eight or nine function calls to compute the total.

Comment: Yea, @martineau I could have definitely used a `try/catch` within this function instead of using a conditional. Good call!

Answer (score 2):

Make you actual board wider and longer by 2 cells, pad the margins with zeros, and work with indices from `1` to `length (or width)-2`.

Comment: Good example of "out of the box" thinking

Comment: @Brent: Actually it's a fairly well-known approach.

Comment: It is. Maybe just literally out of the box padding :)

Comment: Very punny `;-)`: Regardless of its knowness, it's an excellent approach and especially good to know _before_ you've already written a bunch of code with hardcoded index values in it...

Comment: @EugeneSh. got my pun as well.  I know that he didn't invent the technique but applied it to this problem correctly.

Comment: @Brent: I'm embarrassed to have to admit totally missing your pun — as it's a good one, too. I have a tendency to take things very literally...

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace your long expression with a single function call to something like this:

```
def neighbors(a, x, y):
    total = 0
    for dx, dy in [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
                   ( 0, -1),          ( 0, 1),
                   ( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1)]:
        try:
            total += a[x+dx][y+dy]
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return total
```

Since there are only eight possible neighbors, for maximum speed you might want to consider unwinding the loop in the above for the following:

```
def neighbors(a, x, y):
    xm1, xp1, ym1, yp1 = x-1, x+1, y-1, y+1
    total = 0
    try:
        total += a[xm1][ym1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[xm1][y]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[xm1][yp1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[x][ym1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[x][yp1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[xp1][ym1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[xp1][y]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        total += a[xp1][yp1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return total
```

The [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678267/355230) of creating a function to check each x, y of each location will require nine function calls to compute the same value (and the evaluation of a non-trivial conditional expression each time).